# Unable to Upload new APK to Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, tfs

I am trying to close my Xamarin-based deployment pipeline by adding a build step uploading the freshly created APK to google play.

I have followed this guide: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play and uploaded the first version of my app manually from the google play console for internal testing successfully.

Then, after downloading and configuring the extension in TFS as explained here (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play), I created a build step as instructed by providing a JSON file:

[image]

At the end of the build I get the following error:

```
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5203679Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_APKFILE
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5214770Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_AUTHTYPE
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5214770Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CHANGELOGFILE
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5214770Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_LANGUAGECODE
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5214770Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_METADATAROOTPATH
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5225769Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVICEACCOUNTKEY
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5225769Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SERVICEENDPOINT
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5233800Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDATTACHMETADATA
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5233800Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SHOULDUPLOADAPKS
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5239805Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TRACK
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5243231Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_VERSIONCODEFILTERTYPE
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5254154Z ##[debug]loaded 22
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5264505Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5264505Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2019-02-05T15:53:22.5275872Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2019-02-05T15:53:31.1113564Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-02-05T15:53:31.1241977Z ##[error]Unhandled: Unexpected token =
2019-02-05T15:53:31.1241977Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Unhandled: Unexpected token =
2019-02-05T15:53:31.1241977Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Unhandled: Unexpected token =
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Update:

I have noticed that If I try to use an endpoint instead of the Json file, after pasting the private key and hitting ok, reopening the google play endpoint  still has an empty private key field:

[image]

When reopening the endpoint:

[image]

This may just be a way to protect the private key, though.

Is there anybody else who has a similar setup up and running who could give me a hand?
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to post details here directly, we should not have to go elsewhere to asqire the details.

Comment: Please include the relevant information IN YOUR POST.  Don't link to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have recreated the deployment pipeline entirely with the newest version of TFS Express and now everything works.
No idea what I was doing wrong before.